# How to pass an argument which needs quotes in an R function?

Tags: r, country-codes

Here's a non-function part of the quote. It works well.

```r
library(countrycode)
countrycode(df$iso, origin = 'iso3c', destination = 'country.name')
```

I'm trying to put that in a function, but am having trouble as the countrycode function is not recognizing the arguments without 'quotes'.

```r
func <- function(df, ori, dest) {
  countrycode(df, origin = ori, destination = dest)
}

func(df$iso, iso3c, country.name)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the parameters without quotes when the function needs strings? Most of the time when people pass values without out quotes it's because they are column names that are coming from a data.frame or other execution environment. Choosing to require unquoted symbols will make your function much more difficult to programmatically work with. with functions like `Map` and `lapply`. As you sure that's a reasonable requirement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With unquoted input, convert to quoted with `subsitute/deparse` in `base R`

```
func <- function(df, ori, dest) {
   ori <- deparse(subsitute(ori)
   dest <- deparse(subsitute(dest)
   countrycode(df, origin = ori, destination = dest)
 }
```

Comment: Typo : `substitute`

Answer (score 0):

Your function does work, if the variables `iso3c` and `country.name` are defined in the parent environment...

```r
library(countrycode)

df <- data.frame(iso = c("USA", "DEU"))

func <- function(df, ori, dest) {
  countrycode(df, origin = ori, destination = dest)
}

iso3c <- "iso3c"
country.name <- "country.name"

func(df$iso, iso3c, country.name)
# [1] "United States" "Germany"
```

But what you probably want is to pass the string values themselves to the arguments (rather than variable names, which probably do not exist)...

```r
library(countrycode)

df <- data.frame(iso = c("USA", "DEU"))

func <- function(df, ori, dest) {
  countrycode(df, origin = ori, destination = dest)
}

func(df$iso, "iso3c", "country.name")
# [1] "United States" "Germany"
```